How to Select All src Attributes Starting with "data:" Using CSS?
I'm facing a challenge in my web development project and need assistance. I want to select all src attributes that start with "data:" using CSS. Specifically, I'm working with HTML elements where some of the src attributes begin with "data:".
I've tried various methods, but haven't found a solution yet. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.


img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

img[src="data:"] {
   border: 5px solid red;
}
<img src="data:kjowejsdflwrwfjhwerorlowejlfsj" alt="Example">

<img src="img.png" alt="Example">




Which selectors have your tried?

I think you'll have to use JS. Select all elements and then filter them out by src property.

@DanielA.White img[src="data:"] {
border: 5px solid red;
}

If you want to match the beginning of an attribute you can use the ^= comparison operator:


img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

img[src^="data:"] {
   border: 5px solid red;
}
<img src="data:kjowejsdflwrwfjhwerorlowejlfsj" alt="Example">

<img src="img.png" alt="Example">



